# Can someone show me how to get my CSS code to work more than once?

Tags: html, css, drawing

Currently, I have 2 divs, each with a CSS class. They are directly below eachother in the HTML file, and have the identical code. The only difference between the two is the id and class names. Here's the code for the HTML:

```
<div class="myCircle" id="myCircle" top="0px">
</div>
<div id="touchbutton" class="touchbutton" top="0px">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.myCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color:#ff0829;
  -webkit-border-radius: 32.5px;
}

.touchbutton = {
  position: absolute;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color:#ff0829;
  -webkit-border-radius: 32.5px;
}
```

The problem is that only one of the circles is appearing, myCircle. When I make touchbutton of class myCircle, it shows up, but not when it is class touchbutton. Is there something in CSS that I'm missing?

Comment: The `=` sign, following `.touchbutton`, is probably screwing things up, since it's not a valid selector.

Comment: Also, in case you don't know of it, jsfiddle.net is a nice tool for sharing and testing js/html/css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `=` between `.touchbutton` and the `{`.

Also, based on how you have the positioning set up they're going to be stacked on top of one another (unless you're setting `left:` or `right:` somewhere else). I'd remove the top attribute from within the HTML and remember to set different positions in the classes.

Comment: ... You've gotta be kidding me. How did I miss that?

Comment: @CSturgess — You forgot to [validate](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Answer (score 1):

No equals sign after the class. i.e.

```
.touchbutton {
  position: absolute;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color:#ff0829;
  -webkit-border-radius: 32.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove that equal sign from css and check